# Mock method return with one of parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Im tryng to mock the return value with one of parameters, in this way:

```
    when( myService.saveMyEntity( TENANT_ID, DEFAULT_USER, Mockito.any( MyEntity.class ) ) ).thenAnswer(
            new Answer<MyEntity>() {
                @Override
                public MyEntity answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                    return (MyEntity) args[2];
                }
            } );
```

But I got the follow error:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Whats the problem? How is the correct?
Im using mockito 1.9.5 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to either use matchers for all the arguments of `saveMyEntity` method, or for none. You've to change that to:

```
when(myService.saveMyEntity(eq(TENANT_ID), any(User.class), any(MyEntity.class))).thenAnswer(
        new Answer<MyEntity>() {
            @Override
            public MyEntity answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                return (MyEntity) args[2];
            }
        } );
```

Also, as noted from @JBNizet's comment, since you're returning the last argument from your answer, you can use [`AdditionalAnswers.returnsLastArg()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/2fcf9a85692305181d511d439080825b5790bba1/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsLastArg%28%29) factory method:

```
when(myService.saveMyEntity(eq(TENANT_ID), any(User.class), any(MyEntity.class))).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsLastArg());
```

Comment: `thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsLastArg())`. And why not use `eq(TENANT_ID)` rather than `anyInt()`?

Comment: @JBNizet Oh! I'm new to mockito myself. Didn't know about that :)

Comment: I didnt know too. Thanks all.